# Error when using 2 (NOT LIKE) wildcards

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like, multiple-conditions

I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't printing out the right information.

```
SELECT FirstName FROM Customer WHERE FirstName NOT LIKE "P%" OR FirstName NOT LIKE "T%";
```

The table will not show any names starting on P or T if I remove one of the conditions (P or T), and the table will only show the names starting with P or T if I change "NOT LIKE" to just "LIKE" on both. But the moment I use two "NOT LIKE" conditions it shows ALL the names, and neither of my NOT LIKE conditions will execute.

Comment: use `and` instead of `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an AND instead of an OR. Not like P or Not like T will always be true for everything; because one of the statements will always be true.  You want them both to be true, so need an AND.